# Replacing reference with endnote text in Word

Tags: vba, reference, ms-word

I have a text in Word that includes references (1,2,3,...) to endnotes. There are multiple references to the same endnote (for example there are several 1s) created by cross-referencing.

I would like to replace all references with endnote text.

On the internet I have found a code that does that. The problem is that if there are several references to the same endnote, only reference whose position is the first in the document gets to be replaced with text (for example only the first 1, other 1s don't).

I need help how to replace all references with the appropriate endnote text.

```
Sub endnotes2()
  Dim Note As Endnote
  Dim NoteReference As String
  Dim NoteText As String

  For Each Note In ActiveDocument.Endnotes
    With Note
      NoteText = .Range.Text
      NoteReference = .Index
      Call Selection.SetRange(.Reference.End, .Reference.End)
      Selection.Font.Superscript = True
      Selection.TypeText (NoteText)
      Selection.Font.Superscript = False
    End With
  Next Note

  Do While ActiveDocument.Endnotes.Count > 0
    Call ActiveDocument.Endnotes(1).Delete
  Loop

 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Font.Superscript = True
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
  With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = " (^&)" 'The ^& here refers to the "found text", so if we found "abc" we will replace it with "(abc)"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain how you insert footnote references to the same footnote, more than once. As far as I know, that isn't possible in a manner that makes them "true" footnotes (part of the Footnote, or even Endnote) collection, as used in the code you show.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was talking about footnotes, while the word document contains endnotes. Multiple references to the same endnote are created by cross-referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me in my simple test.

Since the cross-reference to an endnote does *not* use superscript by default searching superscript is not a reliable criterium. Also, other things could be superscripted. Cross-references are managed by Word using *`Ref` fields*, and these refer to a *bookmark* placed at the endnote reference when the `Insert cross-reference` commmand is used.

Such bookmarks begin with `_Ref` followed by a longish number. And the fields for endnotes use the name `NoteRef`. So it makes sense to get the bookmark name(s) for the endnote references (there could be more than one), check that they're named using the `_Ref` pattern then search the document for use of the bookmark(s).

In order to "Find" a field code the pattern `^d` is used. So the search term is that, followed by the name of the field code (NoteRef) and the bookmark name. If the search is successful, the field code is deleted and the endnote text is written at this position. The search then continues from this point to the end of the document.

So the code loops through all the endnotes, gets each one's Reference, gets all of its bookmarks, loops the bookmarks, checking the name (as described above) and searches for the NoteRef fields (as described above).

Finally, the original endnote reference is replaced by the endnote text.

```
Sub WriteEndNoteToAllEndNoteRefs()
    Dim sEndNoteText As String
    Dim rngEndNoteRef As Word.Range, rngSearch As Word.Range
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim en As Word.Endnote
    Dim bkm As Word.Bookmark
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each en In doc.Endnotes
        Set rngEndNoteRef = en.Reference
        sEndNoteText = en.Range.Text
        For Each bkm In rngEndNoteRef.Bookmarks
             If Left(bkm.Name, 4) = "_Ref" Then
                Set rngSearch = doc.content
                rngSearch.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = True
                Do
                    With rngSearch.Find
                        .Text = "^d NoteRef " & bkm.Name
                        .wrap = wdFindStop
                        bFound = .Execute
                        If bFound Then
                            rngSearch.Fields(1).Delete
                            rngSearch.Text = sEndNoteText
                            rngSearch.End = doc.content.End
                        End If
                    End With
                Loop While bFound
             End If
        Next
        rngEndNoteRef = sEndNoteText
    Next

End Sub
```